# Regarding a tiling background image that isn't tiling completely

Tags: html, css

I've been reading this site for a few months, and gotten some great answers by searching.  This is my first post, so apologies in advance if I'm not following protocol. :)
I've run into something I can't find a working solution for.

I'm making a centered, 2 column, single page site. The left column is for nav, and is fixed. The right (content) column scrolls, and should expand vertically with added content.  I've added a drop shadow around the two columns which I'd like to expand vertically with the content div, but it stops at the bottom of the screen. I put a red border around the content div to see if I could find anything obvious. I found that the shadow stops tiling at the bottom of the content div, telling me that the content div isn't expanding. I'd set the height on that div to 100%.

I'm not sure if the problem is related to the height settings, or possibly the positioning I've used. I searched the forums and found suggestions to set the body and/or html height to 100%, which I've done. The shadow is the wrapper div (also set to 100%). Still no go.

At this point, I'm at a loss.  It's probably something simple, but I'm just not seeing it. I was going to post the code here, but I didn't want to include irrelevant pieces.  At the same time, I'm not sure which pieces ARE relevant.  So, here's a link to the page, where the html and css can be viewed:
http://modernrelic.com/newsite.html.  If it's better to post it here, please let me know and I'll be happy to add it.

Can anyone see what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with the fact that `#content` is positioned `absolute`ly and `float`ed right. These two properties break it out of normal flow, so you need to remove them.

After having a long mess about with your CSS, there are a few changes you can make to get this working. First, the CSS for `#content` should look like this **with no other properties required**:

```
width: 650px;
margin-left: 350px;
```

The only other change you need to make is to remove `height: 100%` from `#bg-shadow`. That's all I had to change to get it working on Chromium 16 and it's very likely to work on other browsers too.

Comment: Thanks, Jam! This did the trick!  It worked in every browser I tried except IE7. I can live with that. :)

Comment: Not a problem! Don't forget to accept this answer at some point.